# Animate UIViewController content while navigating using TabBar

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am trying to replicate the animation that Google Drive (iOS version) has when navigating from one tabbar VC to another (see below):

[image]

I currently have access to the **fromView** and **toView** when selecting a tabbar item, so I can use UIView.animate() to animate these 2 views:

```
class MyCustomTabBarVC: UITabBarController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }
}



extension MyCustomTabBarVC: UITabBarControllerDelegate  {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        guard let fromView = selectedViewController?.view, let toView = viewController.view else {
          return false
        }


        if fromView != toView {
            fromView.alpha = 1
            toView.alpha = 0.8

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                fromView.alpha = 0

            }, completion: { (_) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                    toView.alpha = 1
                })
            })

        }

        return true
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot understand what type of animation (or chain of animations) is/are used in the case of Google Drive.

The animation I use in the code above will not have the same result. Can anyone with a better understanding of animations help out? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would say, that firstly they use quicker animation (shorter duration) and they're happening at the same time. Plus they are animating **alpha** and **scale** of given views.

I would use something like this:

```
...
    // prepare view
    toView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
    toView.alpha = 0

    // Animate
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], 
    animations: {
       fromView.alpha = 0
       fromView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)

       toView.transform = .identity
       toView.alpha = 1

    }, completion: nil)
```

Is it better?

EDIT:

As we discussed another solution in comments – to get better ways to animate subviews, you can type cast those viewControllers.
Don't forget, that if you embedded for example UINavigationControllers, you have to type cast to that class first!
I've tried it and it works:

```
extension MyCustomTabBarVC: UITabBarControllerDelegate  {

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    // Presented View Controller which should fade out
    if let selectedNC = selectedViewController as? UINavigationController {
        if let myFirstVC = selectedNC.viewControllers.first as? MyFirstViewController {
            // animate fade out
        } else if let mySecondVC = selectedNC.viewControllers.first as? MySecondViewController {
            // animate fade out
        }
    }

    // View Controllers which should be selected
    if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController {

        if let firstC = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? MyFirstViewController {
           // animate fade in
        } else if let firstC = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? MySecondViewController {
            // animate fade in
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

}

Without navigation controller you can simply type cast those like this:

```
...
    if let myFirstVC = selectedViewController as? MyFirstViewController {
      // animate fade out
    }
 ...
```

Comment: Actually this is the correct approach but I played with the values a little bit. Also "toView.alpha" I started it at 0.85 since the 0 value was causing problems (a quick flash of white light). Any idea how to select view elements not to animate (ex. like the search field in Google Drive app)?

Comment: Oh, that quick flash could be connected with the fact, that you are animating whole view of ViewController. Maybe you could solve this + your need of excluding some subviews from animation, if you firstly type cast those view controllers (e.g. guard let yourVC = selectedViewController as? YourViewController ... ). Then you can access individual subviews of given view controllers and it's functions. So you can prepare those animations inside view controllers and then just call something like "yourVC.animateSubviews()".

Comment: That could actually be the solution! Let me try this and I will get back!

Comment: I am trying to cast the shouldSelect viewcontroller to one of my view controllers but I fail. Basically I get the selectedIndex using let selectedIndex = tabBarController.viewControllers?.firstIndex(of viewController)! and then I check against the number of the index. Say index 0 is my HomeVC, then I do: if selectedIndex == 0 { if let vc = viewController as? HomeVC { print("success") } else { print("failed")}. And I get failed all the time! :)

Comment: @christostsang I've edited my original answer with the code I would use to type cast those View Controllers. I don't think you need to use indices.

Comment: indeed the reason it was not working was the UINavigationController! Now it works perfectly!!